# wsdl binding not found in wsdl file

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I've got the following wsdl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/bbf/extern/myMinfin/"   xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/bbf/extern/myMinfin" xmlns:pols="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/bbf/extern/myMinfin/policies"

xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/bbf/extern/myMinfin/">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/bbf/extern/myMinfin/policies" schemaLocation="getPolicies.xsd" />
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name="policiesForPersonRequest">
  <wsdl:part name="policiesForPerson" element="pols:policiesForPersonRequest" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="policiesOutput">
  <wsdl:part name="policies" element="pols:policiesResponse" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="MyMinfinService">
  <wsdl:operation name="getPoliciesForPerson">
    <wsdl:input message="policiesForPersonRequest" />
    <wsdl:output message="policiesOutput" />
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="MyMinfinServiceHTTPBinding" type="MyMinfinService">
  <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
  <wsdl:operation name="getPoliciesForPerson">
    <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
    <wsdl:input>
      <wsdlsoap:body use="literal" />
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
      <wsdlsoap:body use="literal" />
    </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="MyMinfinServicePorts">
  <wsdl:port binding="MyMinfinServiceHTTPBinding" name="MyMinfinService">
    <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:7001/bbf/MyMinfinService" />
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

The xsd behind it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/bbf/extern/myMinfin/policies" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/bbf/extern/myMinfin/policies"
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

<xs:element name="policiesForPersonRequest">
<xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation>The request from where all available policies must be returned.</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="FI_enterpriseNumber">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>The KBO / enterprise number of the financial institution.</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:length value="10" />
          <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{10}" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="RRNOrBIS">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>The national number or bis number.</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:length value="11" />
          <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{11}" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>



<xs:element name="policiesResponse">
<xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation>Available policies.</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="policy" maxOccurs="999">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>A policy.</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="policyNumber" >
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation>Insurance policy number.</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:length value="255" />
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="policyName" type="xs:string">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation>The name of the policy.</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
wsdl:binding "{http://www.minfin.fgov.be/bbf/extern/myMinfin}MyMinfinServiceHTTPBinding" not found in the wsdl: file:/C:/BBF2/FUP_04_Implementation/FUP_00_Source/Project_Folder/BBF_EXTERNAL_CONTRACTS/src/main/resources/myMinfin/myMinfin.wsdl
```

what could be wrong?

Comment: I chose not to make the namespaces etc more compact because, who knows, the mistake may be in there..

Comment: Who does throw this exception? Please describe your environment. I do not see any issue in your WSDL.

Comment: This exceptions is thrown when I'm running the "wsimport myMinfin.wsdl" command in the cmd.

Comment: Try to open the wsdl in other tool like SoapUI or your IDE. It may clarify the issue.

Comment: The wsdl is created / opened in eclipse and doesn't show any errors. SoapUI gives the perfect error "there was something wrong in your wsdl"..

Comment: Could it be some problem in referenced xsd? Try to distill minimum WSDL that still suffers the issue. Simple types, one message, no imports .. We can then open it ourselves.

Comment: I'm indeed going to minimize the input and see if it will work. I'll post it here when / if I've got it.

Comment: I couldn't fix it.. I replaced the wsdl with a more compact one and added my xsd.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Love the error.. Problem is fixed.
replaced

```
xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/bbf/extern/myMinfin"
```

with

```
xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/bbf/extern/myMinfin/"
```

took me 3hours to find!

Answer (score -1):

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not find wsdl:binding operation info for web method XXXX.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:125)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.XXXXX(Unknown Source)
```

If this error occurred then add annotation Webservice to your client side interface which is already developed on service side.
I faced this issue; I have configured Spring with CXF. I have already developed the service and calling it from client.

Hope this will help.